# How to get the correct shape of the tensor in custom dataset

Tags: pytorch

I am using custom `Dataset` class, but the problem is that when I get the data from the `Dataloader` I am left with `array` that has different tensor shape than I want.

shape that I get:       `torch.Size([1, 56, 128, 128])` 
shape that I want:    `torch.Size([1, 56, 1, 128, 128])`

my approach was to:

1) to apply `numpy.expand_dims` on the `array` and get   `torch.Size([1, 1, 56, 128, 128])`

2) then to `np.transpose` on the `array` to get the shape I want `torch.Size([1, 56, 1, 128, 128])`

after first step I am getting the error:

```
raise ValueError('pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got {} dimensions.'.format(pic.ndim))
ValueError: pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got 4 dimensions.
```

if I do the transpose first, none of the combination of `np.transpose(array, axes=(1,2,0))` yields the shape `torch.Size([56, 1, 128, 128])`

if I convert `array` to `Tensor` first and then do `torch.unsqueeze` I get the error:

```
raise TypeError('pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got {}'.format(type(pic)))
TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

here is my code:

```
class patientdataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.annotations = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotations.iloc[index,0])
        # np_load_old = np.load
        # np.load = lambda *a, **k: np_load_old(*a, allow_pickle=True, **k)

        image= np.asarray(np.load(img_path))


        image= np.transpose(image, axes=(1,2,0))
        image = torch.Tensor (image)

        image = torch.unsqueeze(image, dim=1)



        y_label = torch.tensor(np.asarray(self.annotations.iloc[index,1]))

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        return (image, y_label)
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do using None:

```
x.shape
torch.Size([1, 56, 128, 128])

z = x[:,:,None,:,:]

z.shape
torch.Size([1, 56, 1, 128, 128])
```

I got a hint from [here](https://www.aiworkbox.com/lessons/add-a-new-dimension-to-the-middle-of-a-tensor-in-pytorch).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if my answer would help you, but you should use:

- [torchvision.transforms.functional.to_pil_image](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.to_pil_image) to transform tensor to image.
- [torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.to_tensor) to transform image to tensor.

Example

```
import torch
import torchvision.transforms.functional as F
a = torch.FloatTensor(1, height, width)
a = F.to_pil_image(a)
```

Note. images in `torchvision` have to be represented as 3-dimensional tensors of the form `[Channel, Height, Width]`.